# Kotlin Array manipulation

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have an array of int and it requires to send an object in a function and multiply every element in that array with 10 and return a new array. As in kotlin where the function argument are val, so we cannot change the value of current array.

Comment: Hi & welcome to the SO. Please read this first [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you to welcome me on SO. But if you know better answer please tell

Comment: In Kotlin IntArray is an object, and all changes for it, applies to object, that you passed into the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While function arguments are "`val`'s" in Kotlin, meaning you can't modify what object they point to, the object (in your case, the array) can still be mutable.

If you want to mutate the array that's passed to your function, you can certainly do that, this will change the values in the array for everyone who has a reference to it:

```
fun multiplyByTenInPlace(array: IntArray) {
    for (i in array.indices) {
        array[i] = array[i] * 10
    }
}
```

If you want to create a new array instead to return with the new values:

```
fun multiplyByTen(array: IntArray): IntArray {
    return array.map { it * 10 }.toIntArray()
}
```

Or better yet, without creating a list in the middle:

```
fun multiplyByTen(array: IntArray): IntArray {
    return IntArray(array.size) { i -> array[i] * 10 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) or simple use `var` instead.

Comment: you **can't** use var in function's parameters